# Migrate Magento1 Email templates to Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration

I have done a data migration from magento1(M1) to Magento2(M2), so that the email templates that were stores in M1 are also migrated to M2 DB, Now when I try to preview these migrated templates it throw me some errors like,

```
Email template '' is not defined.
```

The solution that comes up in my mind is to copy template files from M1 to M2.

I do not have some expertise in Magento, Can someone please guide if this is even possible to use the M1 templates in M2 or I need to created those templates in M2 from scratch?

or any other idea to get M1 template work in M2 in term of overriding or so?

Comment: Hi, i am facing same issue. Did  you get any solution?

Comment: Hi @JN_newble how to migrate only email templates can you suggest me

Answer (score 4):

## How to fix from ADMIN PANEL

- in admin: **MARKETING > Communications > Email Templates**
- edit template(s)
- in field **Template Content** find string *{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}*
- replace to string *{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}*
- also find string *{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}*
- replace to string *{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}*
- repeat these actions for **MARKETING > Communications > Newsletter Templates**

## How to fix from DATA BASE

If there are many templates, you can replace strings via SQL commands.
Just execute:

```
UPDATE `email_template` SET `template_text` = REPLACE(`template_text`, '{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}', '{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}');
UPDATE `email_template` SET `template_text` = REPLACE(`template_text`, '{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}', '{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}');
UPDATE `newsletter_template` SET `template_text` = REPLACE(`template_text`, '{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}', '{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}');
UPDATE `newsletter_template` SET `template_text` = REPLACE(`template_text`, '{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}', '{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}');
```

Comment: do u have any idea about how to migrate email templates using data migration tool?