# Convert Magento 1 (migrated) email templates to Magento 2 (variables)

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates, magento2.3.5, variables, magento1.7.0.2

Migrated Magento 1 into Magento 2 **does not seem to contain any 'default' Magento 2 email templates (using the Magento 2 migration tool).** It ***only*** contains the Magento 1 email templates that were migrated.

**(If this Magento 2 installation had it, I could have used them as reference)**

None of the templates variables work in Magento 2 when *previewing or emailing*.

The following Magento 1 email template (account registration completed):

```
<!--@subject Welcome, {{var customer.name}}! @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"htmlescape var=$customer.name":"Customer Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url"}
@-->

<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->
<!-- truncated Html just to get to relevant sections @-->
<table>
                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1>Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},</h1>
                            <h3>Account Registration successfully completed.</h3>
```

Results in this : [image: Image show variables, instead of the values]

#### Magento 2 articles found does not mention anything about Magento 1 migrated templates.

*I checked the following articles, but mostly they just discuss **changes between Magento 2 versions***:

- [Email templates](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)
- [Email Magento 2 migration](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html)

**None of those assist me in changing Magento 1 variables into Magento 2 versions.**

### Question

Where / how can I find the equivalent versions.

For instance this template has `{{var logo_url}}`, `{{var logo_alt}}`, `{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}}`

A reference, or a way to browse the code to find the *what is the `customer/order/email address/etc` variables* versions of Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix from ADMIN PANEL

- in admin: MARKETING > Communications > Email Templates
- edit template(s)
- in field Template Content find string {{template config_path=""design/email/header""}}
- replace to string {{template config_path=""design/email/header_template""}}
- also find string {{template config_path=""design/email/footer""}}
- replace to string {{template config_path=""design/email/footer_template""}}
- repeat these actions for MARKETING > Communications > Newsletter Templates

Comment: This answer is a copy of answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244926/migrate-magento1-email-templates-to-magento2 which I looked at before asking this question.
It does not help in my context, I specifically asked **where to get variables** so that I can convert _Magento1_ to _Magento2_ versions, I also mentioned I do not have any Magento 2 templates, this has nothing to do with Magento 1 variables unfortunately, sorry.

Comment: If you don't have any M2 email templates, chances are you've migrated the wrong way. You can refer to this move. I referenced it when migrating my site and everything is working now https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-1-to-magento-2-upgrade.html